# how can I download whastapp images at one time

Tags: whatsapp

If you head to any contact then go to media or links or documents if you select them all there is no way to export them all to an app or camera roll also if you open whatsapp web there is no button for select all you have to select e.g. 3000 photos one by one to save them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found it much easier to export WhatsApp images from the Gallery.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. It might be on topic in [apple.se] / [android.se].

Answer (score 0):

As WhatsApp is closed source and doesnt already offer the option, your best case might be to automate saving it in Whatsapp Web. For e.g. using AutoHotKey to press the Right key (next image), right click, press Down arrow to Save Image (however many times you need) and then to press Enter to save it. Adding in delays where appropriate and you can leave it running to save images. This only works for continous contigous images and isnt foolproof but its a good start to download many images at once.

However, in Android (at least) there's an option to export the chat with or without media - it probably zips it up or something - this might not easily work for you in iOS but perhaps theres a similar export option you can take advantage of, like through Email for example if it supports exporting media.